# How do I get the box shadow to show up on my content-bg?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site called http://ccrccmo.com and I can't get the box-shadow to show up on the content-bg with css.

```
nav{
    background:url(images/nav-bg2.png);
    height:74px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #222;
}
#content-bg{
    background:white;
    margin-top:0px;
    z-index:-1000;
}
```

Comment: If you went to ccrcc.com sorry that was the wrong url. I have the right one posted now.

Comment: I just put inset box shadow on the content-bg and that looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing

```
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 10px #000;
box-shadow: initial;
```

try

```
#content-bg {
background: white;
margin-top: 0px;
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 10px #000;
box-shadow: initial;
}
```